# TFS REST API: a query by ChangedDate returns date precision error when time part is included

Tags: rest, tfs-2015

I am testing it in a browser rest client.
Endpoint:

```
http://server:port/tfs/Collection/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=1.0
```

Payload:

```
{"query":"Select Id From WorkItems Where [System.ChangedDate] >= '2016-03-16T22:02:00.00Z' AND [System.WorkItemType] = 'Bug' order by [System.CreatedDate] asc"}
```

method: POST

result: "You cannot supply a time with the date when running a query using date precision".

If I drop the time part of the datetime, and use `[System.ChangedDate] >= '2016-03-16` it works, but I need more granularity. The answers to similar questions in .NET context suggest using `dayPrecision = false` Is there an equivalent of it in REST api? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't any option to set this to true/false in REST API for now, you can submit a feature request on [VSTS User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services).

The way to do this for now is use [Query Constructor (WorkItemStore, String, IDictionary, Boolean)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb133075(v=vs.120).aspx) in [.NET client libraries](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet).